# java c:foreach loop - shows only one value

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to make comment function and it shows comment only when the user is the first one and the comment is the first as well.
if the user leave comment twice, then second one dosen't show up on comment list.

content_view.jsp

```
//function to list all the comments
function listReply(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "reply/list.do?bId=${content_view.bId}",
        success: function(result){
            $("#listReply").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

ReplyController.java

```
@RequestMapping("list.do")
public ModelAndView list(@RequestParam int bId, ModelAndView mav){
    List<ReplyDto> listReply = replyService.listReply(bId);

    mav.setViewName("replyList");
    mav.addObject("list", listReply);
    return mav;
}
```

replyList.jsp

```
   <c:forEach var="row" items="${list}">
        ${row.memId} &nbsp;&nbsp;(${row.regDate})
        <br>
        ${row.rText}
    </c:forEach>
```

replyDto.java

```
int rId;        // reply no
int bId;        // board no
String rText;    // reply text
String memId; 

public int getrId() {
    return rId;
}

public void setrId(int rId) {
    this.rId = rId;
}

public int getbId() {
    return bId;
}

public void setbId(int bId) {
    this.bId = bId;
}
...
// toString()
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ReplyDto [rId=" + rId + ", bId=" + bId + ", rText=" + rText
            + ", memId=" + memId + "]";
}
```

so when I debug the code, toString() is executing only one time. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did this causing by the web browser not send out the request? if the url is the same, it won't send out the request, just reply with the cache.

Comment: @forqzy oh then how do I resend the request?

Comment: Add a random value in your request

reply/list.do?bId=${content_view.bId}:rand=xxxxxx

Comment: @forqzy Omg it works! I added (new Date).getTime() . Thanks a lot!